# Problems with authentication on Huawei b525s-23a

Tags: c#, huawei-mobile-services

I have a Huawei b525-23a router. Using it's web interface you can send/check SMS but I want to do it automatically from an C# app. I didn't found any API documentation for it so any link will be very good.
I managed to find some HTTPRequests using Chrome but when I use it from C# I get the 125003 error that is according to some google search an authentication problem.

Here are some parts of my code :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // getting SenInfo and TokInfo

        string urlTokenInfo = "http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo";

        HttpWebRequest requestTokenInfo = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlTokenInfo);
        requestTokenInfo.Method = "GET";

        WebResponse responseTokenInfo = requestTokenInfo.GetResponse();

        Stream responseTokenInfoStream = responseTokenInfo.GetResponseStream();

        string responseTokenInfoString = new StreamReader(responseTokenInfoStream).ReadToEnd();

        var rootElement = XElement.Parse(responseTokenInfoString);
        string sessionId = rootElement.Element("SesInfo").Value;
        string tokenInfo = rootElement.Element("TokInfo").Value;

        //_________________________________________________________________________________
        // trying to log

        String urlLogin = "http://192.168.8.1/api/user/login";


        HttpWebRequest requestLogin = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlLogin);
        requestLogin.Method = "POST";

        String XMLLogin;

        String base64Passwd = Base64Encode(passwd); //function for base64 encode

        XMLLogin = " <request ><Username> " + userName + " </Username><Password> " + base64Passwd + " </Password></request> ";

        byte[] requestInFormOfBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XMLLogin);
        requestLogin.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        requestLogin.ContentLength = requestInFormOfBytes.Length;

        Stream requestStream = requestLogin.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestInFormOfBytes, 0, requestInFormOfBytes.Length);

        requestLogin.Headers.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", tokenInfo);
        requestLogin.Headers.Add("Cookie", sessionId);


        WebResponse raspuns = (HttpWebResponse)requestLogin.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStreamLogin = raspuns.GetResponseStream();
        string responseStrlogin = new StreamReader(responseStreamLogin).ReadToEnd();

    }
}
```

The response that I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><error><message></message><code>125003</code></error>
```

Thank you for your time reading this and any response will be apreciated.

Mihai Stanciu

Answer (score 1):

125003 error means token verification failed.

Check the session and token values in the first html resource request file